# ComboBox Issue when turning it Enable property to false

Tags: vb.net, combobox

Well programers, i hava the following problem, but let me explain you a little bit my applicaction I'm working with vb.NET and I'm making an applicacion for a physiologist, and i need to change the Enable property of the Combo Box to False when it change, but i have the problem that, just at the moment i click on the Combo it get locked, i mean the property change to False, I have the following code.

```
Private Sub cbResp1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cbResp1.Click

    Select Case cbResp1.Text
        Case Is = "Buena"
            Correctas = Correctas + 1
        Case Is = "Mala"
            Correctas = Correctas
    End Select

    Me.cbResp1.Enabled = False

End Sub
```

Hope you can help me, Thanks

Comment: What do you want to happen when the combobox is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Private Sub cbResp1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cbResp1.Click
    Select Case cbResp1.Text
        Case "Buena"
            Correctas = Correctas + 1
            Me.cbResp1.Enabled = False
        Case "Mala"
            Me.cbResp1.Enabled = False
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried it but it didn't work... i have to click on the Combo box twice to make it lock. I really dont know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell you that I've fixed it! Take a look at the event. the problem was that I tried to lock it when it got clicked, but I had to program the lock in the SelectedIndexChanged event instead. thanks for your help